# PostgreSQl - Is there a way to do Upsert from one table to another?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I want to do insert or update from one table to another in PostgreSQl.

What I've achieved till now is to make two SQL commands one for insertion and one for updating. So is there a way to do this in just one command?

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_table_a (LIKE table_a INCLUDING DEFAULTS);
COPY tmp_table_a FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV;
UPDATE table_a a SET (id, column1, column2) = (tmp.id, tmp.column1, tmp.column2) FROM tmp_table_a tmp WHERE a.id = tmp.id;
INSERT INTO table_a (id, column1, column2) SELECT tmp.id, tmp.column1, tmp.column2 FROM tmp_table_a tmp WHERE tmp.id not in (select distinct id from table_a);
```

Comment: `insert into table_a select ... from table_b on conflict ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Funny thing is I've tried this command before and got an exception but now it works. seriously don't know why :D you can post it as an answer and I'll accept it